# Ignore Selections "DAX Function ALL" not working

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I got a situation here, i have a measure for **"Total Sales"** with following expression

> Total Sales = CALCULATE(SUM(Sale[total]), ALL(Customer))

I have a visualization in which i am displaying product-sales by customer.

If i make a customer-name selection in that visualization then this measure (mentioned above) changes its value. Why?

Both scenarios are shown in following screenshot (measure-value without customer-name selection & measure value with customer-name selection:

[image]

Data-Model Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: because you are selecting an entire row, so your total is now filtered by product name (Laptop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the formula to ignore **both tables**

**Total Sales = CALCULATE(SUM(Sale[total]), ALL(Customer), ALL(Product))**